# Custom certificate for Spring Boot build pack

Tags: spring-boot, buildpack

I am trying to include a custom certificate authority for my Spring Boot application that is packaged using build packs (using default Packeto setup and Spring Boot 2.5). According to the [docs](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates), I can include a custom certificate in my image by creating a new binding of type `ca-certificates` and including the raw PEM file.

But it's not clear *where* inside my project to include these artifacts, or if there are any special naming conventions to follow so that the `pack` command picks up my binding. I have a typical Spring Boot layout with Maven, and based on the [sample project](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/samples/tree/main/ca-certificates) I have tried this layout:

[image]

It's just a directory named `binding` at the top level of my project, which contains the `type` file and my CA. The `type` file is a copy/paste from the sample project and just contains the text `ca-certificate`.

But my certificate is not getting included in the final Docker image. I have also tried moving this directory inside the `src/main` area with no luck.

What is the proper setup to get a custom CA included in my image?

Answer (score 3):

My assumption that the Spring Boot Maven plugin would know where to look for new bindings was incorrect. Starting with Spring Boot 2.5, you can now pass binding information as part of the plugin configuration:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <bindings>
                            <binding>${project.basedir}/platform/bindings:/platform/bindings</binding>
                        </bindings>
                    </image>
```

So you can keep the binding directories (type file + CA cert file) anywhere you want, you just have to tell the plugin where they exist so it can be passed to the `pack` command. After I did this, I saw my cert get added during the build:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo CA Certificates Buildpack 2.3.2
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Reusing cached layer
[INFO]     [creator]       CA Certificates: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Added 1 additional CA certificate(s) to system truststore
```